# Nginx Bad gateway error code 502 archivematica

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, 502

hey everyone I am a new to Linux. I have installed archivematica on my VM using VMware Workstation. I have followed the guide below, but when i try to access this machine using its IP address which is 172.16.0.12:8000 or even without the port number, I get the error message

```
502 Bad Gatewaynginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu).
```

even when i use `curl` i get the same error

https://www.archivematica.org/en/docs/archivematica-1.13/admin-manual/installation-setup/installation/install-ubuntu/#install-pkg-ubuntu
Here are some of the logs

```
arch@archeieve:~$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2022/06/18 12:13:33 [error] 1200#1200: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "127.0.0.1:8000"
ii2022/06/18 12:14:47 [error] 1200#1200: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.0.236, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "172.16.0.12:8000"
2022/06/18 12:14:47 [error] 1200#1200: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.0.236, server: , request: "GET/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/favicon.ico", host: "172.16.0.12:8000", referrer: "http://172.16.0.12:8000/"


arch@archeieve:~$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2022:12:13:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
172.16.0.236 - - [18/Jun/2022:12:14:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.16.0.236 - - [18/Jun/2022:12:14:47 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://172.16.0.12:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.16.0.236 - - [18/Jun/2022:12:18:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
172.16.0.236 - - [18/Jun/2022:12:18:07 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "http://172.16.0.12:8000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

And here is the configurations' lines of the IPtables

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
```

what are the main steps to identify and solve this problem?

Comment: Whatever is supposed to listen on port 8001 is not doing so. Check if all services are running.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know This error " failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream " means that the service that nginx wants to pass the connection to is not up or not responding bellow timeout limit.

So check that the services listed in the tutorial that you linked are up such as

```
sudo systemctl status archivematica-mcp-server
sudo systemctl status archivematica-storage-service
sudo systemctl status archivematica-dashboard
```

If one of them is not started ( active ) then investigate why it didn't started

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).